# Flutter Next Level Button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I created a button and i need that when the user pressesit, to send him from the level he was to the next level, my app has 300 levels, if the user is on level 1, and he presses that button it will send him to the 2nd level. Here is the screen for all the buttons for the levels [image: Image for the Levels screen]][1], here is the image for the the level button[[image: Next Level screen and button]][2], so this button only has to send the user to the next level.

```
child: GridView.count(
                          crossAxisCount: 4,
                          children: List.generate(data!.length, (index) {
                            return InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(20),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            RenditFjaletButton(
                                              QuizList: data[index].word,
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${index + 1}',
    And here is the Code for the button
    
                                                     child: FlatButton(
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            null;
                                                          },
                                                          child: Image.asset(
                                                            'assets/next_small.png',
                                                            height: 80,
                                                            width: 80,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I dont know how to make the button when pressed to send the user to the next level, if he is on level 43, send him to level 44

Comment: you like send data on `RenditFjaletButton`?

Comment: onPressed (){
Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            RenditFjaletButton(
                                              QuizList: data[index].word,
                                            )));
}
if i change QuizList: data[index].word, to like QuizList: data[1].word, when i press the button it will display the words of 2nd level, instead of that i just need the level that i am right now +1 for the words

Comment: You were trying to send data of next level (button) to the another screen...!!?   just  increment the index  like, `onPressed (){ Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => RenditFjaletButton( QuizList: data[index+1].word, ))); }`.

Comment: i cant figure out how to use the index of the cards, to when you press the button

Comment: you are already using , you card list is based on `data[]`. look at your piece of code `QuizList: data[index+1].word`  . you were already selected data of that button , which you pressed.

Comment: i need to use the same index, so when i press the button i can do data[index+1].word, im creating the button on another class, and another screen,

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Navigator.push()`. Have a look at the [Flutter Docs on Navigation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) to add these features to your app.

Comment: when i use it, if i do  QuizList: data[1].word, when i press the button it will display the words of the second level,  i just need the level that i am right now +1 for the words.

Comment: In that case, you should make a variable to store the level. Make the button have `onPressed: () { yourVariable++; }` as the function.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the index by one on `push`

```dart
 RenditFjaletButton( QuizList: data[index+1].word, )))
```

For last index, show game over screen.

You can make `QuizList` nullable by adding `?` on `RenditFjaletButton` class and removing required or create another bool variable like `isGameOver`

```dart
RenditFjaletButton( QuizList: data[index+1].word,
  isGameOver: data[index+1].word>data.length )))
```

Here is a test widget to increase index, based on second screen.

```dart
class _TState extends State<T> {
  bool _gotoNextLevel = false;
  // on new page it will set to false again
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        floatingActionButton: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("L1"),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    content: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _gotoNextLevel = true;
                              });
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
                            },
                            child: Text("1")),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text("+cancel")),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Current level ${1 + (_gotoNextLevel ? 1 : 0)}"),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => Page2()
));
```

In place of page2 you can place the name of the page where you want to go navigate.